# What is the relation between the structure group and fundamental group of an affine manifold?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry

I have picked up a vague idea that the structure group of transition functions between coordinate charts on an affine manifold is specified by a representation of it's fundamental group. Could someone please say why and how?

Comment: Could you start by specifying what do you mean by an "affine manifold": There are two competing notions in the literature. One notion refers to a manifold equipped with an affine connection. The second notion insists that this connection is flat (such manifolds are also called "flat affine").